# How can I remove a specific format from string with RegEx?

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of string like this

```
$16,500,000(@$2,500)
$34,000(@$11.00)
$214,000(@$18.00)
$12,684,000(@$3,800)
```

How can I extract all symbols and the `(@$xxxx)` from these strings so that they can be like

```
16500000
34000
214000
12684000
```

Comment: hint: replace anything that isn't a number `[^0-9]` with nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\(.*?\)|\$|,
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/42

```
$re = "/\\(.*?\\)|\\$|,/m";
$str = "\$16,500,000(@\$2,500)\n\$34,000(@\$11.00)\n\$214,000(@\$18.00)\n\$12,684,000(@\$3,800)";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the end `(@$xxxx)` characters, you could use the regex:

```
\(\@\$.+\)
```

and replace it with nothing:

```
preg_replace("/\(\@\$.+\)/g"), "", $myStringToReplaceWith)
```

Make sure to use the `g (global)` modifier so the regex doesn't stop after it finds the first match.

Here's a breakdown of that regex:

> **\(** matches the ( character literally
>   **\@** matches the @ character literally
>   **\$** matches the $ character literally
>   **.+** matches any character 1 or more times
>   **\)** matches the ) character literally

[Here's a live example](https://regex101.com/r/hT2vB4/1) on regex101.com

---

In order to remove all of these characters:

> $ , ( ) @ .

From a string, you could use the regex:

```
\$|\,|\(|\)|@|\.
```

Which will match all of the characters above.

The `|` character above is the regex `or` operator, effectively making it so
**$** OR **,** OR **(** OR **)** OR **@** OR **.** will be matched.

Next, you could replace it with nothing using [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), and with the `g (global)` modifier, which makes it so the regex doesn't return on the first match:

```
preg_replace("/\$|\,|\(|\)|@|\./g"), "", $myStringToReplaceWith)
```

[Here's a live example](https://regex101.com/r/vJ5hV9/1) on regex101.com

---

---

So in the end, your code could look like this:

```
$str = preg_replace("/\(\@\$.+\)/g"), "", $str)
$str = preg_replace("/\$|\,|\(|\)|@|\./g"), "", $str)
```

Although it isn't in one regex, it does not use any `look-ahead`, or `look-behind` (both of which are not bad, by the way).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i don't need anything inside the bracket

Comment: Looks like I misread the question. I just updated the answer to make it more on-topic (deletion would work, but [not deleting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37738) could help others that come to look at this question).  @vks has the better answer here.